# Can someone help me with my background gradient. It's not appearing properly in the Webpage

Tags: css

I am trying to rotate a gradient but I am facing problem to display it properly on the screen.

It's appearing like this:
[Screenshot of the webpage with gradient.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWnNp.png)

Here's the code for the gradient:

```
.gradient{
    -webkit-linear-gradient(234deg, #ff8a40, #fd5068, #dc4588);
    background: linear-gradient(216deg, #ff8a40, #fd5068, #dc4588);
    padding: 55px 5% 5% 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that's on `html` or `body`. Try setting `min-height: 100vh`

```css
body {
  -webkit-linear-gradient(234deg, #ff8a40, #fd5068, #dc4588);
  background: linear-gradient(216deg, #ff8a40, #fd5068, #dc4588);
  padding: 55px 5% 5% 5%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: @dragonball lol corker. Are you british by chance? I have a few friends in the uk that call me corker. Apparently it's slang for an attractive girl or something? you're welcome :)

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 I am not allowed to mark the answer within 12 minutes :P

Comment: @MichaelCoker :D

Comment: @MichaelCoker marked the answer :D thank you so much for the help.